# IIS 7 IP and Domain Restrictions not working (set to deny by default)

Tags: iis-7, restrictions

I have a website on IIS and I am trying to block access to one particular folder from anywhere but our LAN. To experiment, I have added both an explicit deny rule for one particular machine on the same network:

[image]

and I have also set the module to deny unspecified clients:
[image]

But whatever I do I can still access the directory from the machine at 192.168.1.4.

I tried restarting the website to see if that needed to be done for the changes to take effect, but same result.

What am I doing wrong?